# Random numbers in array where the mean is a whole number

Tags: java, arrays, performance, average, mean

I'm working on a a game where I have to generate an int array of 4 elements randomly. My problem is that the mean of all the array elements always have to be a whole number.

Example :
array 1 {4 , 2 , 3, 7} , the mean of the array is 28,75 which is not what I'm looking for,

array 2 {3 , 7 , 6 , 4} , the mean is 20 which is good

Now I could make a loop where I check if the mean of the randomly generated numbers is a whole number but that doesn't seems like an efficient way to do that.

The game I'm working for is mean sum for those who know it.

Comment: Unless you can come up with a formula to prove out the means and generate only those specific values, I'm not sure how else you'd go about accomplishing it.  Effectively you're bruteforcing this approach.

Comment: Pick a target mean, multiply it by 4 to get an overall sum; then pick random numbers which sum to this number (i.e. pick a random number less than the sum, subtract from the sum; repeat).

Comment: _array 1 {4 , 2 , 3, 7} , the mean of the array is 28,75_...really? Neither the mean or sum of that array is 28.75.

Comment: @AndyTurner - It's not clear that one can do that and still get a uniform distribution.  (Though to be fair, the OP didn't specify a distribution.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth indeed. No distribution was stipulated.

Comment: Are you looking for the sum or the mean?

Comment: The usual definition of "mean" is the same as "average". What do you mean by "mean"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mean is a whole number, then the sum must be divisible by 4.

```
int[] n = new int[4];
```

Pick four numbers, and calculate their sum:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  sum += (n[i] = random.nextInt());
}
```

Calculate the remainder of `sum / 4`:

```
int r = sum % 4;
```

So you now need to adjust the sum so that `sum % 4 == 0`. You can either:

- subtract `r` from any of the elements of the array:

  ```
  n[random.nextInt(4)] -= r;
  ```
- or add `4 - r` to any element:

  ```
  n[random.nextInt(4)] += 4 - r;
  ```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/76Vclr)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a target mean `m` and random integers `n1`, `n2`.

Your array is [`m-n1`, `m+n1`, `m-n2`, `m+n2`]. Haven't thought about what the properties of this distribution would be, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following function does what you want, given arguments of how many values you want to generate (`n`) and what's an upper limit for the sum of the values (`max`).

```
private static Random r = new Random();

public static int[] makeSet(int n, int max) {
   // The next line guarantees the result is divisible by n
   int currentMax = n * (1 + r.nextInt(max / n));
   Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();

   // Generate a set of unique values between 0 and the currentMax,
   // containing those bounds
   s.add(0);
   s.add(currentMax);
   do {
      s.add(r.nextInt(currentMax));
   } while(s.size() <= n);
   Integer[] values = new Integer[n + 1];

   /*
    *  Convert to array, sort the results, and find successive
    *  differences.  By construction, those differences WILL sum
    *  to the currentMax, which IS divisible by the number of
    * values generated by differencing!
    */

   s.toArray(values);
   Arrays.sort(values);
   int[] results = new int[n];
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      results[i] = values[i+1] - values[i];
   }
   return results;
}
```